# How read dynamic arrays in bash <4.3 version

Tags: arrays, bash, shell, unix, scripting

I have a problem reading the contents of dynamic arrays.

Here I create dynamic arrays:

```
    j=0 
    tab="project_" 
    for i in "${unique[@]}"
    do

            echo -n $i 
            eval ${tab}${i}=\(\)
            #eval $tab$i[0]="test"
            while read text 
            do
            if [ "${i}" == "${text}"  ]; then
                    echo " - OK "
                    eval ${tab}${i}=\(\)
                    k=0
                    z=0
                    x=0
                    for k in "${array[@]}"
                    do
                    z=`expr ${z} + 1`

                    if [[ "${i}" == "${k}" ]]; then
                            eval $tab$i[x]+=${array[`expr $z + 1`]}
                            x=`expr ${x} + 1`
                    fi

                    done

            fi
            done < "$allProjects"


            for name in "${tab}${i[@]}"
            do
                    echo "$name"
                    for n in "${name[@]}"
                    do 
                         #eval echo "\${${tab}${i}[@]}"   #this line will work, but I do not want to use eval                                        
                         echo ${n} # <-- Here I would like to read it with 
                                   # the echo command, but it does not work
                                   #  I get the name of a dynamic array, but 
                                   #  I want to get its contents.
                    done
           done
          #eval echo  \${#${tab}${i}[@]} 
          #eval echo "\${${tab}${i}[@]}"
    done
```

Maybe it's confusing because it's a snippet of code.
The premise is to create dynaic arrays based on values from another array and add the word project_ to the beginning.
Later on to these dynamically created arrays enter values from yet another array.

Comment: Yes it's confusing because it's a snippet of code and not a proper explanation of what you're actually trying to do, and what is blocking you.

Comment: It works, but now I would like to know if it is possible to read values in these dynamically created arrays by the echo command, because it gives me the possibility of further processing.
The goal is to retrieve individual values from dynamic arrays and further process them.

Comment: `expr` is unnecessary; `z=$((z + 1))` and `${array[z+1]}` are sufficient.

Comment: I found the answer echo "${!n}"
But I get results in one line, and I would like everyone from the new line 
It does not work properly: echo -e "${!n}\n"